# Why nested local function binds `this` to window instead of the parent

Tags: javascript, scope, this

I was reading some [documentation about javascript](http://iwiki.readthedocs.org/en/latest/javascript/js_core.html#apply-invocation) and stumbled upon the following code example:

```
var o = {
  value: 1,
  outer: function () {
    var inner = function () {
      console.log(this);  //bound to global object
    };
    inner();
  }
};
o.outer();
```

It outputs `window`.

I cannot figure out **why** is the `this` keyword bound to the global object (`window`) instead of the parent object (`outer`).
If you want to access `outer` from `inner`'s scope, you have to pass the `outer`'s `this` (which is just like passing `outer` itself) to its local `inner` function as an argument. So, as expected:

```
var o = {
  value: 1,
  outer: function () {
    var inner = function (that) {
      console.log(that);  //bound to global object
    };
    inner(this);
  }
};
o.outer();
```

outputs `outer`.

Isn't it a bit of a nonsense that in `outer`'s scope `this` is bound to the object itself (i.e. `outer`), while in the `inner`'s scope, which is local to `outer`, `this` is re-bound to the global object (i.e. it overrides `outer`'s binding)?

The [ECMAScript specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3) states that when entering the execution context for function code if the «caller provided thisArg» is either **null** or **undefined**, then `this` is bound to the global object.

But the following:

```
var o = {
    outer: function () {
        var inner = function () {
            console.log('caller is ' + arguments.callee.caller);
        };
        inner();
    }
}
```

outputs the object `outer` itself:

```
caller is function () {
    var inner = function () {
        console.log('caller is ' + arguments.callee.caller);
    };
    inner();
}
```

---

**On a side, but probably relevant, note:**
In *strict mode* the first code snippet outputs `undefined` instead of window.

Comment: It's because how you're calling `inner` - `inner();`. The value of `this` is set by the way you call the function. Any anyways, `inner` has no relation to `outer`, it's just a local variable. If you used `console.log(this);` inside of `outer` and called it like: `var a = o.outer; a();`, you'd get `window`. You may think it's nonsense, but it's designed that way - you need to learn how to use it properly.

Comment: "The ECMAScript specs states that when entering the execution context for function code if the «caller provided thisArg» is either null or undefined, then this is bound to the global object." - haven't you answered your own question? `inner()` does not specify the thisArg.

Comment: @Ian so does the scope where the call is made not matter at all?

Comment: @NadirSampaoli I don't believe so, in terms of how the value of `this` is set at least.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté yes, `inner()` doesn't specify the `thisArg`, but doesn't it correspond to `arguments.callee.caller`?

Comment: @NadirSampaoli no. Unless you make an explicit relationship like `inner(this)`

Comment: `arguments.callee` is deprecated and forbidden in strict mode, I'll have to check the docs for `.callee.caller` when I get home.

Comment: @JanDvorak Errr you mean like `inner.call(this);`? Either way, getting the value to `inner` isn't as simple as just calling `inner()`. And even with `inner(this)` or `inner.call(this)`, it doesn't guarantee the value of `this` in that context is "correct"

Comment: Oh, here are the docs for the non-standard Function.caller https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller

Comment: @Ian `inner.call(this)` will guarantee the inner's context is the same as the outer's one. You can't get much more correct than that.

Comment: So Function.caller refers to the calling context, I don't see any relation with thisArg which is set with `.call`/`.apply` or implicitly through `obj.method()` notation

Comment: @JanDvorak Very true, I guess I just mean that the `outer` context could be "incorrect" in the way it's called...like `var f = o.outer; f();`, but that's up to the OP calling it "correctly". Just trying to point that out for the OP

Comment: All your comments are much appreciated. I think I get the points now: `this` and the context are not related; `this`, unlike scopes, doesn't «cascade» (forgive the term); unless explicit, a call's thisArg is undefined, and thus bound to the global object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just how it the language works.

*Every* time a function is called, `this` will be reset.  In a nested (inner) function it does not inherit the value from the enclosing scope the way other (explicitly declared) variables are.

*By default* `this` will be set to `window`, *unless* the function is *invoked* as:

- `myObj.func(arg1, ...)` or
- `func.call(myObj, arg1, ...)` or
- `func.apply(myObj, [arg1, ...])`

in which case `this` will be equal to `myObj`

A function called any other way, even if it was originally defined as a property of an object (i.e. `var func = myObj.func; func()` will use `window`.

There's also a utility function called `.bind` which wraps a function reference in such a way that you can provide a specific value which will always be used as `this`:

```
var myFunc = myObj.func;                // obtain reference to func
var bound = myFunc.bind(someOtherObj);  // bind it to "someOtherObj"

bound();                               // this === someOtherObj
bound.call(myObj)                      // this still === someOtherObj
```

Answer (score 6):

This is because `this` is set when the function is *run*, not when it's defined.

For example:

```
var o = {
    func: function(){
        console.log(this);
    }
};
```

When you call `o.func()`, you are doing so in the context `o`, so it works as expected.

Now let's say you do this:

```
var f = o.func;
f();
```

This will not work as expected.  This is because when you call `f()`, it doesn't have any context attached to it, so `this` will be `window`.

You can fix this by using `.call` to change the value of `this`.

```
var f = o.func;
f.call(o);  // sets `this` to `o` when calling it
```